# Gnome horizantal workspace without gnome-extension

Tags: fedora, gnome, gsettings

How to make `gnome` workspace to be horizantal?

I have a very bad experience with `gnome` extensions, therefore I do not intend to install them.

I want to do them with `gsettings`, as far as now I could disable dynamic workspace and change number of them by these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides dynamic-workspaces false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 6
```

Now I have 6 vertical workspace, but I want them to be in 3 rows and 2 columns.

My OS is Fedora 28.